# C# Arrays Help Needed Please

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, class

Im a beginner at programming using C#, and my lecturer has given us a tricky project.
I've managed to complete all of it except... arrays!

Long story short, I've got 5 textboxes all of which take input from the user.  This information is to be stored into an array and then listed in order (date of birth order) displaying in a rich text box, I've listed the code I've managed to do below:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
      bc[0] = new Student();
      bc[1] = new Student(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), "Mary", "Ford");
      bc[2] = new Student(1254, "Andrew", "White");
      bc[3] = new Student(1256, "Liam", "Sharp", " ");
      bc[4] = new Student(1266, "Michael", "Brown", " ");

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
         string bcString = bc[i].studentToString() + "\r\n"; 
         richTextBox1.AppendText(bcString);
      }
   }
}    

CLASS "Student":
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_2
{
    class Student
    {
        private int accountNum;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string balance;

        // first constructor
        public Student()
        {
            accountNum = 0;
            firstName = "";
            lastName = "";
            balance = "";
        }

        // second constructor
        public Student(int accValue, string firstNameVal, string lastNameVal)
        {
            accountNum = accValue;
            firstName = firstNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            balance = "";
        }

        // third constructor
        public Student(int accValue, string firstNameVal,
                             string lastNameVal, string balanceValue)
        {
            accountNum = accValue;
            firstName = firstNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
            balance = balanceValue;
        }

        public int AccountNum
        {
            get
            {
                return accountNum;
            }

            set
            {
                accountNum = value;
            }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }

            set
            {
                firstName = value;
            }
        }

        public string studentToString()
        {
            return (Convert.ToString(accountNum) + " " + firstName +
                    " " + lastName + " " + balance);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where have you defined `bc`?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Please post any compiler errors or exception messages.

Comment: What are the symptoms of your problem? Error messages? Unexpected behaviour? Please help us help you!

Comment: You say that the Student should be ordered by Date of Birth, but your class student has no DateOfBirth property

Comment: wow fast replies thanks! im not getting any error messages, im just trying to find a way to create an array and list them in a rich text box. i have not added all my code but rest assured DOB is defined. 'bc' has not been defined in my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class Student implement the IComparable interface, then sort for the field DateOfBirth (if it exists). This example works on the AccountNum but should be trivial to change with a DateOfBirth

```
Student[] bc = new Student[5];

bc[0] = new Student();
bc[1] = new Student(9999, "Mary", "Ford");
bc[2] = new Student(1254, "Andrew", "White");
bc[3] = new Student(1256, "Liam", "Sharp", " ");
bc[4] = new Student(1266, "Michael", "Brown", " ");

// Here the sort on the AccountNum
Array.Sort(bc);

// A StringBuilder instead of the RichTextBox for testing....    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    string bcString = bc[i].studentToString() + "\r\n"; 
    sb.Append(bcString);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

CLASS STUDENT: (Just the part for the IComparable)

```
class Student : IComparable
{
    .....


    public int CompareTo(object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Student otherStudent = obj as Student;
        if (otherStudent != null) 
            return this.accountNum.CompareTo(otherStudent.AccountNum);
        else 
        throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Student");
    }
    ....

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, what I am looking for is the input to be from textBox1, textBox2 etc... For example                              bc[1] = new Student(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "Ford");
bc[2] = new Student(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "White");

Comment: How about, if the user adds records via textbox would i be able to add it into a txt file, and then read the file and display it in order via a rich text box perhaps?

Comment: Usually this task is accomplished by two forms. The first one displays the Student record (in a grid, listview or something), the second form displays the data for a single student where the user could update values presented. When the second form is confirmed, data is copied back to the bc array at the correct index. But this is a bit broad to explain here. I suggest to divide your task in smaller steps and ask appropriate question for each step

Comment: Sure, i would like the user to enter information into the text boxes, this information is to be stored. After 10 students have entered their information, I would like to display all 10 students in the GUI, in order via DOB.